# Embedding layer with one-hot encoding

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, encoding, embedding

Let's assume that I have one-hot encoded input data. I will give an example from [that stack exchange link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270546/how-does-keras-embedding-layer-work/305032#305032)
Suppose that we have just 2 sentences:

```
Hope to see you soon
Nice to see you again
```

Therefore, we have 7 different words, let's say their unique integer indexes (tokenized representations) are:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

[5, 1, 2, 3, 6]
```

Thus one-hot representation is the first sentence **Hope to see you soon** is that:

```
[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,0,0]]
```

Now, I know the working principle of Keras embedding layer. It works like a lookup table and because of that reason all examples that I can find take tokenized inputs. The same [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270546/how-does-keras-embedding-layer-work/305032#305032) also explains the embedding layer working approach.

However, I wonder that, if I give one-hot encoded inputs to keras embedding layer, does it work properly? Because I know that it works with either tokenized inputs or one-hot encoded inputs. Also, does it create a performance difference?